# bash process monitor script echo empty when no process found

Tags: linux, bash, loops, conditional-statements, ps

I've created a process monitor to check for the presence of a running process, and if found we need to check its parent to determine if it is acceptable or not, it's a security check basically.  It works great when I look for running processes and gives me output that I expect.  However, for some reason when no process is found, it's spitting out an empty line instead of "ok" like I would expect.  I know that the variable rmanRUNNING is being populated with a 0 if no process is running, I've checked, so I'm not sure why the first if statement isn't just failing over to the else and then performing the echo "ok" line before closing.  Any help will be GREATLY appreciated.  See below:

```
#!/bin/bash

rmanRUNNING=`ps -ef|grep rman|egrep -v grep|wc -l`

if [ "$rmanRUNNING" -gt "0" ]
 then
    PPIDs=($( ps -oppid= $(pgrep rman)))
    kshddPID=($(pgrep -f 'ksh.*/rman_dd.ksh'))
    for i in "${PPIDs[@]}"
    do
        :
        for j in "${kshddPID[@]}"
        do
            :
            if [ "$i" == "$j" ]
                then
                    result="ok"
            else
                result="bad"
                break
            fi
        done
        if [ "$result" == "bad" ]
            then
                break
        fi
    done
    echo "$result"
else
    echo "ok"
fi
```

I must be missing something simple, I just can't seem to isolate it, if I simplify this to be just the if with the current conditional and then an echo followed by an else and an echo, it seems to work right, so I feel it's something to do with the loops inside the main if that are causing some error that I don't see.  Or, perhaps it has to do with a misunderstanding of how break works so I'm breaking out to a point where I echo an empty "result" variable and then terminating, I'm just not sure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think it's related to the problem, but why don't you use `pgrep` when assigning to `rmanRunning`?

Comment: Run your script with `bash -x` so it will show you the lines as it executes them. This should tell you where it's going wrong.

Comment: You'll get empty output if `$rmanRunning` is greater than 0, but `$kshddPID` is empty, because the inner `for` loop won't do anything.

Comment: @barmar the first comment was quite helpful.  that does show me that apparently it SHOULD be giving me what I want, as can be seen with this output:bash -x ./rman_check.sh
++ wc -l
++ pgrep rman
+ rmanRUNNING=0
+ '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
+ echo ok
ok

Comment: @Barmar with that said, I'm confused by the second, I don't understand why the for is even being evaluated, if the if statement of 0 > 0 should not evaluate to true and therefore the inner for loop shouldn't even be considered?  plus, it appears that it should be echoing ok, at least when I execute bash -x ./rman_check.sh but when I simply execute ./rman_check.sh I get the empty line.  Puzzled.

Comment: I'm saying this happens when `$manRunning > 0` but there are no `rman_dd.ksh` processes.

Comment: To further that, if I do execute this by explicitly calling bash: bash ./rman_check.sh I do get the ok output, but if I run ./rman_check.sh EVEN if I've explicitly switched my shell to bash it returns the empty line.

Comment: I just figured it out. When you run `./rman_check.sh`, that process matches `ps -ef | grep rman`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ps -ef | grep rman | grep -v grep` is matching the process name `rman_check.sh`. So when you run your script, `$rmanRunning` is not `0`, because it's counting itself.

Use `pgrep` with the `-x` option so that it matches the command name exactly, rather than looking for a substring.

```
#!/bin/bash

rmanRunning=$(pgrep -x rman | wc -l)

if [ "$rmanRUNNING" -gt "0" ]
 then
    PPIDs=($( ps -oppid= $(pgrep -x rman)))
    kshddPID=($(pgrep -f 'ksh.*/rman_dd.ksh'))
    for i in "${PPIDs[@]}"
    do
        :
        for j in "${kshddPID[@]}"
        do
            :
            if [ "$i" == "$j" ]
                then
                    result="ok"
            else
                result="bad"
                break
            fi
        done
        if [ "$result" == "bad" ]
            then
                break
        fi
    done
    echo "$result"
else
    echo "ok"
fi
```

However, there's also a problem with your overall logic. If you have two `rman_dd.ksh` processes and they each have an `rman` child, you'll report `bad` when you compare one parent with the other. A simpler way is to just sort the two PID lists and compare them.

```
PPIDs=$(pgrep -x rman | sort)
kshddPIDs=$(pgrep -f 'ksh.*rman_dd.ksh' | sort)
if [ "$PPIDs" = "$kshddPIDs" ]
then echo "ok"
else echo "bad"
fi
```

Comment: Sure enough, and thanks for the suggestion at the bottom as well.  Appreciate it!

Comment: BTW, if I had suggested instead that you use `set -x` at the beginning of the script, you would have seen it in the debugging. I'll remember that for the future.